# Object to Cookie in PHP

Tags: php

I am starting my studies in PHP and I'm having problems with an application:
I need to put information of an object in PHP for a cookie and then receive a cookie to object again on another page.
anyone has any solution to this problem?

The information I want to store in cookie is just some information preferably Customer as background color, size of windows.

```
<?php  
class Client {    

private $id;
private $pSize;    
private $color;

function __construct($id) {
    $this->id = $id;
}

public function getPSize() {
    return $this->pSize;
}

public function setPSize($pSize) {
    $this->pSize = $pSize;
}

public function getColor() {
    return $this->color;
}

public function setColor($color) {
    $this->color = $color;
}
}
?>
```

In a page index.php i have:

```
<?php      
  include_once 'Client.class.php';
    //Test Preference Client
    $client = new Client(1);
    $client->setColor("#000000");        
    $client->setPSize(200);       

    //using Serialize to put to Cookie
    $StringClient = serialize($client);

    //Store to Cookie
    $_COOKIE['PreferenceClient'] = $StringClient;
```

?>

In a another page i get the inrofmation:

```
 if(isset($_COOKIE['PreferenceClient'])){
       // Unsing Unserialize to Object
        $objClient = unserialize($_COOKIE['PreferenceClient']);

        //Test data:
        echo $objClient->getColor();            
        //Continue with Performing changes to the client if the information exists...
    }
```

**I solved the problem. Thanks to everyone who helped.**
before i had tried only get the cookie information without serialize
Guys, this is my first post, I apologize if I did something wrong.
I have to make something up for you?

Comment: Have you tried using a session?

Comment: look on the edited answer maybe u know what is the role of serialize

Comment: You have amount of answer to store any object. Now we must ask you: What have you tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could store objects in string (like cookie does) via serialize, unserialize.

```
setcookie ($name, serialize($object));   // set object

$object = unserialize($_COOKIE[$name]);   // get object
```

But remember that using this approach could be dangerous. [PHP Object Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/PHP_Object_Injection)

You could use `json` instead of `serialization` to store `stdClass`, it would be safe enough.

```
setcookie ($name, json_encode($object));   // set object stdClass

$object = json_decode($_COOKIE[$name]);   // get object stdClass
```

But it's prefer to use [session](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) to store your data. You could even store object without calling serialize, unserialize. But `__sleep`, `__wakeup` magic still works.

[setcookie](http://php.net/setcookie), [$_COOKIE](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php), [serialize](http://php.net/serialize), [magic with serialization](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep).

Comment: Do not ever store serialized objects in cookies.  It is far too dangerous.

Comment: @KevinSchroeder, answer includes relative link about this problem.

Comment: Yes, I saw that.  However, this isn't just "could be dangerous" or "not preferred".  As a pattern, it is exceedingly dangerous.  If there were ever a justification for the <blink> tag it would be to surround the words "don't ever do this in real life".

Answer (score 3):

The answer is: **You don't.**

Whenever you take data from the client and use it in your code,
you have to implement security that prevents the case when the user changes his client data and injects something unexpected into your server. The client is easily able to fake and change cookie data, and thus to change your object.

Example:

If we serialize the object from Alma Do's answer and store the values in a cookie, the client/user could see our database auth settings from

```
public function __sleep() {
    return array('server', 'username', 'password', 'db');
}
```

The client now can change his cookie to use a fake server instead of your server, fake your login / user table and pretend to be admin.

I think this is a case of [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), please let us know what exactly is your goal.

Comment: It is equivalent to store private data in object in cookie, or just in cookie. It's does not make any sense.

Comment: Can I upvote this answer about 50 times?  Though I would change the answer to "You don't ever, ever, ever, ever do this"

Answer (score 1):

This sounds more then a session function. You shouldn't transfer data over a Cookie. In Cookies you only save short information like a session token or a hash or some settings. To transfer and hold data the PHP session function is much better.

http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.session.php

In your session you can serialize some data if you want or save only an array or a value.

```
session_start(); // on every page

$_SESSION['test'] = "123123";

echo $_SESSION['test'];
```

Comment: OP didn't mentioned sessions. May be it's only about cookie data transmission.

Comment: It's possible "I am starting my studies in PHP" but this sounds a bit like a global solution.

Answer (score 0):

to send serialized object you must use a specified thing like `time()` to bypass `SPAM` and control the `timeOut!`

```
session_start();  

setcookie('myobject',serialize("Myvalue"),(time()+(3600*24*30)));
```

be sure to get stored on the session :

```
     unset($_SESSION['myobject']);
```

Store your object

```
     $_SESSION['myobject'] = unserialize($_COOKIE['myobject']);
```

Restore your Obecjt :

```
$mySeriaLizedObject = $_SESSION['myobject'];
```

Comment: @downvoter ? have u read the paragraph in bleu sky whene u click on the down arrow?