# Cookie return stdClass Object only

Tags: php, json, serialization

I have and array of few objects. And those objects are instances of different classes.

Suppose

```
array (
 [0] => Car Object(
   [id] => 6
   [name] => Texi 1
 )
 [1] => Bed Object(
   [id] => 40
   [name] => Sleeping Bed
 )
)
```

Now I am saving this to cookie, and before saving I am using using `json_encode` on it.

While retrieving If I use `json_decode($data)`, I am getting an array of stanadrd objects, and if I use `json_decode($data, true)`, then I am getting only array of arrays !!!

So instead of stdClass objects how can I get actual objects ? is it possible ?

I have tried `serialize(json_decode($data, true));` but in vain. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: @alice, check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/a/20096924/4841755.

Answer (score 0):

use `serialize($data)` instead and `unserialize($data)` to retrieve the original data.

don't use json_encode before serializing as it will turn the classes into StdObject or Arrays.

Comment: You said you used: serialize(json_decode($data, true)); which means the data you serialized was json encoded. Serialize it without json encoding the data. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: I **strongly** advise against doing this, especially in cookies - it automatically becomes a remote code execution vulnerability.

Comment: I will not be able to save it in cookie then, it needs to be a string @NiekvanderMaaden